# Can I charge a power bank through charging MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

I have:

- 15" 2018 MacBook Pro with USB Type-C ports.
- Xiaomi PowerBank 3 Pro with 1 Type-C input/output and 2 regular USB outputs.

Can I charge my MacBook via MagSafe, and simultaneously charge Xiaomi power bank via Macbook type-C port without any harm?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/357006/237687

Answer (score 1):

I have no clue about the Xiaomi, but I charge my power bank while charging my 15" MacBook Pro all the time...

Actually, I generally have my power bank charging my iPad Pro and my Apple Watch Valet, which is charging my iPhone and Apple Watch.